# Why is my method behaving differently when called from different places?

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I am making a graphical sudoku solver. Currently, I have a board where the user can enter the starting board configuration. Then they can click "solve" and it will solve the puzzle. To display the results, the method "displayResults()" is called:

```
void displayResult(int[][] boardArray) {
    sudokuBoard.updateArray(boardArray);
    sudokuPanel.repaint();
    sudokuPanel.revalidate();
}
```

This then calls the updateArray() method:

```
    void updateArray(int[][] boardArray) {
      for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if(boardArray[i][j] == 0) sudokuArray[i][j] = "";
            else sudokuArray[i][j] = Integer.toString(boardArray[i][j]);

            squares[i][j].removeAll();
            squares[i][j].add(new JLabel(sudokuArray[i][j], JLabel.CENTER));
            squares[i][j].repaint();
            squares[i][j].revalidate();
        }
     }
  }
```

This works fine for "solve", displaying the results.

I have a menu bar in my program with an "open" item. This is meant to read in a text file (with an initial board configuration) and show the contents on the board.
I have tried calling the "displayResult()" method after reading in the file (passing in the resulting array). Unfortunately, nothing displays in the grid when it is called. Strangely, I have tried clicking solve, and the correct results will then appear in the grid.

```
sudokuPanel // the panel in the main window that contains the grid
sudokuBoard // an object of a Board class that contains all of the board info
squares // a 9x9 array of JPanels, representing the grid
sudokuArray // an array of Strings, containing the up to date information about the board configuration
```

I am having a similar problem with another method, however I am guessing that they are related. The read() method is:

```
protected void read() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXT FILES", "txt", "text");
    chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    if(chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try {
            File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);

            while(input.hasNext()) {
                sb.append(input.nextLine());
                sb.append("\n");
            }

            input.close();

            readInToArray(sb);
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File does not exist");
        }
    }
    else return;
}
```

And readInToArray(), which calls displayResult():

```
private void readInToArray(StringBuilder sb) {
    int[][] newArray = new int[9][9];
    String[] lines = (sb.toString()).split("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            char c = lines[i].charAt(j);
            newArray[i][j] = Character.getNumericValue(c);
        }
    }
    if(!checkArray(newArray)) {
        errorMessage("Incorrect configuration");
        return;
    }
    displayResult(newArray);
}
```

Comment: Of course it is.   The expectation is that the revalidation/repaint will cause the new components to register their peers and then draw in the ui thread.   Perhaps they want to `revalidate()` and then `repaint()`, in that order, instead of `repaint()` followed by `revalidate()`?

Comment: Please show the code that loads the text file. Maybe opening the text file is executed in a different thread than the event despatching thread thread? In this case you need to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to execute displayResult

Comment: @NineBerry Thanks. I have updated the post with those methods.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have fixed it. I was calling the method from an extended class that seemed to be the problem.